# Virtual Machine Host within Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost

Right now I've got ubuntu desktop with virtual box and dozens of virtual ubuntu machines... I'm setting up the next ubuntu server today, and I never thought about the "Virtual Machine Host" in the tasksel @ installation. There's nothing clear on it via Google... What is it exactly? Is it a virtual host machine (like virtualbox) within ubuntu server itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much, yeah.  That task select option installs [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page), which is certainly a capable virtualization solution.

More specifically, it installs the [ubuntu-virt-server](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-virt-server) meta-package.